# Can't connect to a DB: database is closed

Tags: mysql, go

I have the following project structure:

```
-main.go
-db
--dbinit.go
```

In `dbinit.go` i have the following code:

```
package db

import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

var Db *sql.DB
var err error

func init() {
    Db, err = sql.Open("mysql", "myDBCreds")
    defer Db.Close()
}
```

and in `main.go` i have:

```
package main 

import (
    db "./db"
)

func main() {

    defer db.Db.Close()

        sqlStatement := `INSERT INTO table (field1, field2)
            VALUES ($1, $2)
        `
        _, err := db.Db.Exec(sqlStatement, param1, param2)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
```

but `main.go` keeps throwing an error:

> sql: database is closed

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `defer Db.Close()` runs as long as your `init` function returns.

Comment: So how should i make sure the DB stays open?

Comment: don't close it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a previously asked question

> The returned DB is safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines and maintains its own pool of idle connections. Thus, the Open function should be called just once. It is rarely necessary to close a DB.

Aka, don't close it.

Comment: Ok, so just our of curiosity - why do many examples include `defer db.Close()` if it never closes?

Comment: @Gambit2007 in their examples that's what they explicitly want - to close it.

Comment: The problem is you're closing it when init returns, so by the time your query is running it is already closed. You could close it in main but according to the documentation you don't need to.